# Get size of string literal parameter

Tags: c, visual-studio-2015

Some functions have a signature requiring a string, and the size of that string. For example:

```
BOOL WINAPI WriteConsole(..., const VOID *lpBuffer, DWORD nNumberOfCharsToWrite, ..., ..);
```

It would be incredibly convenient if we could use a string literal as an argument and have the size of that literal be passed to the size argument. For example:

```
WriteConsole(..., "MyString", sizeof(param(1)), ..., ..);
```

Where param(n) would return the nth argument. This would save having to write out a variable to hold a string which isn't needed otherwise.

Does anything like this exist, particularly in Visual Studio?

Comment: lets remember that `sizeof()` is a compile time activity so cannot return the length of a string when that string was created during execution time

Comment: BTW: the size of a string literal parameter would be the size of a char pointer (4 or 8 depending on the underlying architecture and the compiler parameters)

Comment: Having tested it myself, sizeof returns the length of the string literal as it's actual length, the same with a stack allocated char array. For a pointer to a string, then what you say is true. This was intended to be compile time anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, nothing like this exists in Visual Studio. It is presumably done this way so that you can send partial strings, e.g.:

```
WriteConsoleW(hConOut, L"Hello" + 2, 2, ...);
```

would write "ll" to the console associated with the `hConOut` handle.

You can create your own function-like macro for string literals by writing something like:

```
/* Needed for _countof macro in MSVC. */
#ifdef __cplusplus
#include <cstdlib>
#else
#include <stdlib.h>
#endif

/* Use _countof(array) where possible, else use
 * sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0])
 * for the number of units in the string literal.
 */
#ifdef _countof
#define WriteConString(hConOut, str, pdwWritten) \
    WriteConsole(hConOut,                        \
                 (str),                          \
                 _countof(str),                  \
                 (pdwWritten),                   \
                 NULL)
#else
#define WriteConString(hConOut, str, pdwWritten) \
    WriteConsole(hConOut,                        \
                 (str),                          \
                 sizeof(str) / sizeof(*(str)),   \
                 (pdwWritten),                   \
                 NULL)
#endif
```

If you didn't care about C++ or [the `_countof` macro](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms175773.aspx), you could shorten the code to only include the last `#define`.

However, this will only work for string literals and statically arrays of chars. `malloc`, `HeapAlloc`, etc. all return pointers, so `_countof(my_array_of_32767_elts_as_ptr)` (and the comparable `sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0])` expression) would result in a very small number rather than the number of elements in the array. Pointers don't encode the number of elements in the array.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I didn't think about the macro side of things. I'll see how I like using that and adjust what is necessary. Also useful to learn about _countof.

Answer (score -1):

I don't understand your question.

A C style string is null terminated so the function you call can easily find the end of the string by searching for the first null character in the string.

Eg functions like strcmp do not require a length.

If you are talking about arrays without a termination identifier then yes usually function will be of type:

```
int func1(const T* data, size_t length);
```

Or similar.

Comment: Where have you seen a C-style string? It's a void* pointer with a byte count. Besides this doesn't attempt to answer the question.

Comment: Your question is: Get size of string literal parameter

Comment: The function does not take a c-style string so the additional feature of these vs. raw pointers (the terminal zero) is irrelevant, as is strcmp. Finally, you don't *answer* by saying such functions usually take a pointer and a size - OP had realized that. The question is: how do you pass both the value and the size without repeating the literal.